# JSONObject exception: No value for message

Tags: android, json

I encountered this familiar exception developing an android app

> No value for message

And i'm sure the JSONObject i have contains what i'm looking for:

here is my JSON Object, and you can format it to better understand it here:http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1438734076389483_1440132306249660", 
      "from": {
        "category": "Community", 
        "name": "AKA", 
        "id": "14387376389483"
      }, 
      "message": "TEST TEST", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/14387340769483/posts/14401323069660"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/14387376389483/posts/14402306249660"
        }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
        "description": "Public", 
        "value": "EVERYONE", 
        "friends": "", 
        "networks": "", 
        "allow": "", 
        "deny": ""
      }, 
      "type": "status", 
      "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
      "created_time": "2014-07-14T18:49:43+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2014-07-14T18:49:43+0000", 
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "84207420", 
            "name": "Akira Yuki"
          }, 
          {
            "id": "14387346389483", 
            "name": "AKA"
          }
        ], 
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "after": "MTQzODczNDA3NjM4OTQ4Mw==", 
            "before": "ODQyMDQ3NDIw"
          }
        }
      }
    }, 
    {
      "id": "1438734076389483_14399988596342", 
      "from": {
        "category": "Community", 
        "name": "AKA", 
        "id": "1438734076389483"
      }, 
      "message": "MEssage test number twooooo", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/143873076389483/posts/143999881956342"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/143873076389483/posts/143999819596342"
        }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
        "description": "Public", 
        "value": "EVERYONE", 
        "friends": "", 
        "networks": "", 
        "allow": "", 
        "deny": ""
      }, 
      "type": "status", 
      "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
      "created_time": "2014-07-14T10:58:20+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2014-07-14T10:58:20+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "143873476389483_1439998362929721", 
      "from": {
        "category": "Community", 
        "name": "AKA", 
        "id": "1438734076389483"
      }, 
      "message": "Never give up", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/143873406389483/posts/143999836292721"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/143873076389483/posts/139998362929721"
        }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
        "description": "Public", 
        "value": "EVERYONE", 
        "friends": "", 
        "networks": "", 
        "allow": "", 
        "deny": ""
      }, 
      "type": "status", 
      "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
      "created_time": "2014-07-14T10:55:16+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2014-07-14T10:55:16+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "1438734076389483_1439998316263059", 
      "from": {
        "category": "Community", 
        "name": "AKA", 
        "id": "1438734076389483"
      }, 
      "message": "lemme try", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/143873476389483/posts/143998316263059"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/143734076389483/posts/143998316263059"
        }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
        "description": "Public", 
        "value": "EVERYONE", 
        "friends": "", 
        "networks": "", 
        "allow": "", 
        "deny": ""
      }, 
      "type": "status", 
      "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
      "created_time": "2014-07-14T10:54:54+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2014-07-14T10:54:54+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "143873407639483_1439990399597184", 
      "from": {
        "category": "Community", 
        "name": "AKA", 
        "id": "143873407389483"
      }, 
      "message": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/143734076389483/posts/143990399597184"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/143734076389483/posts/143999039957184"
        }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
        "description": "Public", 
        "value": "EVERYONE", 
        "friends": "", 
        "networks": "", 
        "allow": "", 
        "deny": ""
      }, 
      "type": "status", 
      "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
      "created_time": "2014-07-14T10:12:51+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2014-07-14T10:12:51+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "143873407689483_143998952930603", 
      "from": {
        "category": "Community", 
        "name": "AKA", 
        "id": "1438734076389483"
      }, 
      "message": "hello", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/143734076389483/posts/14399895420603"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/143873407638483/posts/143989542930603"
        }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
        "description": "Public", 
        "value": "EVERYONE", 
        "friends": "", 
        "networks": "", 
        "allow": "", 
        "deny": ""
      }, 
      "type": "status", 
      "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
      "created_time": "2014-07-14T10:05:09+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2014-07-14T10:05:09+0000"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/143873476389483/feed?limit=25&since=140363783", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/143873406389483/feed?limit=25&until=140532308"
  }
}
```

AND HERE IS MY CODE THAT THROWS THE EXCEPTION

```
                            JSONObject oneRowJSONObj = response
                                    .getGraphObject()
                                    .getInnerJSONObject();

                            JSONArray dataJSONArray = oneRowJSONObj
                                    .getJSONArray("data");

                            Log.v(TAG, dataJSONArray.toString());

//Working

                            for (int i = 0; i < dataJSONArray.length() ; i++) {
                                JSONObject c = dataJSONArray
                                        .getJSONObject(i);

                                // Storing JSON item in a Variable
                                String message = c.getString("message");


                                Log.v("ONE ROW", message);//Here i get the exception
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... you're iterating over the items in the `data` section:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataJSONArray.length() ; i++) {
    JSONObject c = dataJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

But then assuming that each item you get in that array is the "message" one:

```
String message = c.getString("message");
```

But unfortunately it doesn't just contain that. The array will have all of the keys in the `data` subsection, including: id, from, message, actions, privacy, etc.

So it's likely (but not guaranteed) that your first iteration is instead getting a `JSONObject` that only has the key "id". Since you're not doing any sort of check to see if `c` has a "message" value (it doesn't), you're getting the exception. You can't call `getString()` if the key doesn't exist. You can do `if (c.has("message")`, or you can call `optString()` to give it an optional parameter.

Comment: Thank, the check process worked. It's actually `c.has("message")` and not `c.hasString("message")`

Comment: @user3838247 whoops - couldn't find my code using that and just went off memory. Will correct.